# accuracy value under f1-score in classification report

Tags: scikit-learn

Consider this

```
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

which prints

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
           2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

    accuracy                           0.60         5
   macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

As far as I understand, the `accuracy` value is not a class-specific metric, but a global one, calculated across all classes and thus doesn't have its own `precision`, `recall`, or `support`. Is there any *specific* reason why it shows up under the `f1-score` column and not under, let's say, the first column of `precision`? I also tried supplying the parameter of `output_dict = True` to `classification_report` and it too just has one value for the `accuracy` key.

```
classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)
```

which prints

```
{'0': {'precision': 0.5,
  'recall': 1.0,
  'f1-score': 0.6666666666666666,
  'support': 1.0},
 '1': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1-score': 0.0, 'support': 1.0},
 '2': {'precision': 1.0,
  'recall': 0.6666666666666666,
  'f1-score': 0.8,
  'support': 3.0},
 'accuracy': 0.6,
 'macro avg': {'precision': 0.5,
  'recall': 0.5555555555555555,
  'f1-score': 0.48888888888888893,
  'support': 5.0},
 'weighted avg': {'precision': 0.7,
  'recall': 0.6,
  'f1-score': 0.6133333333333334,
  'support': 5.0}}
```

which only makes me think that both the `support` value in the `accuracy` row and the placement of `accuracy` in the string format of the report might be coincidental. Is there any relation that I'm missing or is it just how the report is printed?

Comment: These measures are [highly problematic](https://fharrell.com/post/classification).